# Why not nested schemas in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I only use PostgreSQL, and never will switch databases softwares ever again in my life, so I don't care about being compatible with some theoretical "SQL standard" which for all practical purposes doesn't exist in reality.

I like the idea of "schemas", and I know very well what they are, but one thing that bothers me is that you cannot nest them. Thus, you can only have one "category" and any "sub-categories" will have to be part of the table name.

Why not have nested schema support? Since "schemas" are not in the SQL standard anyway, why did they not go the whole way and allow nested schemas?

Granted, I have not yet *really* needed this, but it seems like it would be useful in theory and for various complex situations.

Comment: I'm a PostgreSQL fan also and I'm intrigued by your post but don't think that I understand exactly what you're driving at? Could you expand on it a bit please - maybe give a small simple example in DDL/DML of what you mean precisely?

Comment: Why do you think that schema are not part of SQL standard, have you seen in mentioned somewhere? Second, can you elaborate on what advantages you see with nested schemas? What would the advantages be for be able to use schema x.x and x.y over schema xx and xy?

Comment: @Lennart I can see use cases for nested schemas, same as for nested directories on the file system. But the benefit of standard compliance (there are people that **do** care about it, like the ones that want to write portable SQL) outweights that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I certainly agree that standard compliance is a good thing, and that it is something to strive for. In reality, most - if not all - vendors have extensions of there own that deviate from the standard. I'm not advocating anti-standard constructions, I was merely curious what the benefits might be, since I never really felt a need for it.

Comment: This could be useful for the same reason that nested or hierarchical namespaces exist in programming, or  other applications like DNS. Even file directories are organized similarly. Sure, I could create two directories called `topdir_subdir1` and `topdir_subdir2` but having `topdir/subdir1` is way more convenient. Likewise, this could allow, for instance, assigning privileges in a hierarchical fashion, for example, a state or city, within a country. Queries and other operations could also benefit from this approach. Upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

> Why not have nested schema support

Because the SQL standard doesn't define them. And yes, schemas **are** defined in the SQL standard, as are catalogs (which are another level of namespace).

Postgres' databases are roughly equivalent to the standard's catalog, except that the standard would require the ability to do-cross catalog (=database) queries.

In the standard `some_catalog.some_schema.some_table` is a valid table reference and could be use with `other_catalog.some_schema.some_table` in the same query. - [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)